# How to extract value of variable inside two curly bracket in javascript (instafeed.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an app with instafeed.js.
Instafeed give us option called "template" so we can get info about an image in instagram. For example : caption, link, likes, image, etc.

In this case, I have try to extract value of the caption.
Here what I've tried :

```
var str = "{{caption}}";
var harga = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

FYI : the {{caption}} value is : "MotoGP Tshirt (150)". My goal is to get the value inside ( ) so the final output is "MotoGP Tshirt, Price : $150".

When I try this :

```
var str = "MotoGP Tshirt (150)";
```

It work perfectly. But when I use {{caption}} like this :

```
var str = "{{caption}}";
```

It doesn't work. So how to store {{caption}} into a variable so I can generate the price.

Full source code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var str = "{{caption}}";
var harga = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"));

    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: xxxxxxx,
        accessToken: 'xxxxxxxx',
        template: '<div class="col-md-3"><p><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" width="100%" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive img-rounded" /></a></p><p>{{caption}}</p><p><font color="#F12938"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{likes}}</font></p>'+harga+'</div>',
        sortBy : 'most-recent',
        limit : 8,
        resolution : 'standard_resolution',
        filter: function(image) {
        return image.tags.indexOf('carefour') >= 0;
        }
    });
    userFeed.run();

$('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
        userFeed.next();
    });
});    

</script>
```

Thanks for your help. I really need help.

Comment: Did you try `filter` function to run above logic?

Comment: Can you please provide your full code?

Comment: I've added my full code. Can u help me to find the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Check my ans and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below and let me know if this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var str = "{{caption}}";
    var harga = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"));

        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'user',
            userId: xxxxxxx,
            accessToken: 'xxxxxxxx',
            sortBy : 'most-recent',
            limit : 8,
            resolution : 'standard_resolution',
            filter: function(image) {
                if (image.caption && image.caption.text) {
                    // Do your logic to change text and assign it to below variable
                    image.my_caption = ''; // Assign variable here
                } else {
                    image.my_caption = image.caption;
                }

                return image.tags.indexOf('carefour') >= 0;
            },
             template: '<div class="col-md-3"><p><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" width="100%" class="img img-thumbnail img-responsive img-rounded" /></a></p><p>{{model.my_caption}}</p><p><font color="#F12938"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{likes}}</font></p>'+harga+'</div>',
        });
        userFeed.run();

    $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
            userFeed.next();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Okay, I am trying. Thanks. BRB

Comment: Hi Dude, it doesn't work yet. The {{caption}} still can not be extracted. :(

Comment: inside the filter option what value are you getting for `image.caption1 && `image.caption.text`.

Comment: Try removing `var str = "{{caption}}"; var harga = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"))` since that will always be an empty string: harga equals {{caption}}.substring(-1,-1), since {{caption}} doesn't contain any '(' characters. Just add {{caption}} manually to the template, since as written, you won't have a {{caption}} in the template string.

Comment: Yeah! It work. I use image.caption.text instead of {{caption}}. By the way, what the different of image.caption and image.caption.text? Thanks.

Comment: @HendraSetiawan Could you post a full working example? I have exactly the same problem. How does your template string look like?

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern will grab the (anything) string from your input. Then you can just chop off the first and last character of the result to end up with the value between ().
If your data is always in the form where the price is at the end, yyou won't even need the regex and can just use your own function and change the first one to indexOf instead of lastIndexOf. The regex will work for strings like 'Moto Helmet (120) size A' as well. If your data between the braces will always be a number, you can edit the regex to only find numbers between (), if needed.

You could also expand this by using the regex in a replace() call on the string, if you want to immediately update the string from 'Something (150)' to 'Something, Price: 150'

Edit: could you explain a little bit more if this is your problem? Or is the problem that you can't convert the {{caption}} to the string containing the price? Since your code doesn't really explain where the MotoGP string comes from.

```
var pattern = /\(.*\)/,
    wrapped = pattern.exec('MotoGP Tshirt (150)'),
    result = wrapped[0].substring(1, wrapped[0].length - 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it still doesn't work.
I've tried this :
wrapped = pattern.exec("{{caption}}"), but it still doesn't work..

Comment: That won't work with this pattern. Where does {{caption}} get transformed into 'MotogGP Tshirt? Is that something instafeed does for you? The code you posted only contains the string {{caption}}, where you need to have the moto string to actually be able to get the value.

Comment: Motogp (150) come from Instagram caption. Check this out : http://instafeedjs.com/#templating

Comment: I Still don't get it, but that's probably because I've never used the instagram API. But for all I know `var str = "{{caption}}";
    var harga = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,str.lastIndexOf(")"))` will always just be an empty string. Deepaks solution looks like he only changes the caption string After the image has been fetched, so I'm thinking you'll have to add the regex inside that filter function .